# Encontrar posición de una fecha en un array de fechas javascript

Tags: javascript, array, date

Tengo un array de fechas:

```
let fechas = [Sun Jul 07 2019 13:05:19, Fri Jun 26 2020 10:09:45]
```

Y quisiera saber la fecha mas reciente y su indice.

Para saber la fecha mas reciente tengo lo siguiente:

```
let fechaReciente = new Date(Math.max(...fechas));
```

Pero  no logro saber su indice, al parecer indexOf no funciona bien con las fechas. Agradeceria la orientación, soy bastante nueva con JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta con este código:

```js
    let fechas = ["2018-06-07","2018-06-30","2018-06-01","2018-06-21","2019-07-20"];
    
    
    let arrayFechas = fechas.map((fechaActual) => new Date(fechaActual) );
    
    
    var max = new Date(Math.max.apply(null,arrayFechas));
    
    let indice=0;
    
    for (let index = 0; index < arrayFechas.length; index++) {
        if (arrayFechas[index].toUTCString()===max.toUTCString()) {
            indice=index;
        }
        
    }
    
    
    console.log("max indice" , indice) 
    console.log("valor maximo" ,max.toUTCString())
```

El método indexOf no funciona porque al momento de usar la función Math.max la fecha toma un valor diferente al que esta en el array.